# NoSuchMethodError on JNI with ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm developing an app for android that uses JNI code to do some CPU intensive calculations. One of my native methods on java passes an ArrayList as argument to the JNI layer.

When I try to use ArrayList's get(int index) with:

```
jmethodID getAtIndex = env->GetMethodID(listClass, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object");
```

I'm getting:

```
NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='get' signature=
'(I)Ljava/lang/Object' in class Ljava/util/ArrayList;
```

However, when I use javap -s java.util.ArrayList to get the signatures for that method I get the exact same signature than the one I'm using on my JNI code.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon on the end of the type signature, Java class type signatures are of the form:

```
L fully-qualified-class-name ;
```

So `Object` would be `Ljava/lang/Object;` and the full type signature for the method would be `(I)Ljava/lang/Object;`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick though I ended going for another solution!

Answer (score 3):

You have the signature wrong. Don't construct JNI signatures by hand: copy and paste from the output of javap -s. In this case you're missing a semicolon.